# bash, get line form file with condition for particular column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've got file with two columns, for example line of this file looks like this: username,data

```
username,20150706
```

I'm trying to get lines that dates in the second column are older than eg. 20151231.

**EDIT, SOLUTION:** I want to do it in a loop and read the dates (the second column of the file) then compare it with another date, eg. 20151231. Then if date is let say older than 20151231 write whole line (username,date) to file. And here's how I do it:

```
date1=20151231
while read -r line;
    do
            date2=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f2);
            if (( date2 < date1 ));
                    then
                    echo "$line" >> filename2;
            fi
    done < filename
```

So one little problem solved :)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: sample data always helps

Comment: I would use perl, since basic commands are not great for date calculations.  The perl script would receive the date you want as the limit.  Then extract the date form the file, and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this with awk:

```
awk -F',' -v threshold=20151231 '$2<=threshold' file
```

hope this helps you!